# Optimize this query for 1000000+ rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, web-applications, crud

I need to pull the data and write it to a csv file but its taking too much time and too much ram. What is wrong with it and what can I do? Also, I feel like there's a redundancy in the query itself. I'm doing this with PHP.

Here's the query

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 SELECT * FROM vicidial_closer_log
USE INDEX(call_date)
WHERE call_date BETWEEN '1980-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-12 23:59:59';
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 SELECT * FROM vicidial_closer_log
USE INDEX(call_date)
WHERE call_date BETWEEN '1980-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-12 23:59:59';
SELECT a.call_date,
   a.lead_id,
   a.phone_number
   AS customer_number,
   IF(a.status != 'DROP', 'ANSWERED', 'UNANSWERED')
   AS status,
   IF(a.lead_id IS NOT NULL, 'inbound', 'outbound')
   AS call_type,
   a.USER
   AS agent,
   a.campaign_id
   AS skill,
   NULL
   AS campaign,
   a.status
   AS disposition,
   a.term_reason
   AS Hangup,
   a.uniqueid,
   Sec_to_time(a.queue_seconds)
   AS time_to_answer,
   Sec_to_time(a.length_in_sec - a.queue_seconds)
   AS talk_time,
   Sec_to_time(a.park_sec)
   AS hold_sec,
   Sec_to_time(a.dispo_sec)
   AS wrapup_sec,
   From_unixtime(a.start_epoch)
   AS start_time,
   From_unixtime(a.end_epoch)
   AS end_time,
   c.USER
   AS
   transfered,
   a.comments,
IF(a.length_in_sec IS NULL, Sec_to_time(a.queue_seconds),
Sec_to_time(a.length_in_sec + a.dispo_sec))
   AS duration,
Sec_to_time(a.length_in_sec - a.queue_seconds + a.dispo_sec)
   AS handling_time
FROM   temp1 a
   left outer join temp2 c
                   ON a.uniqueid = c.uniqueid
                   AND a.closecallid < c.closecallid
GROUP  BY a.closecallid
```

I've uploaded screenshot of table structure and the indices.
[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uUjP.png)
[Indices of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tw5v.png)

Thanks.

UPDATE:
SHOW CREATE TABLE vicidial_closer_log

```
vicidial_closer_log     CREATE TABLE `vicidial_closer_log` (
`closecallid` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lead_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
`list_id` bigint(14) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`campaign_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`call_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`start_epoch` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`end_epoch` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`length_in_sec` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_number` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`user` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`comments` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`processed` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`queue_seconds` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
`user_group` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`xfercallid` int(9) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`term_reason`       enum('CALLER','AGENT','QUEUETIMEOUT','ABANDON','AFTERHOURS','HOLDRECALLXFER',    'HOLDTIME','NOAGENT','NONE','MAXCALLS') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT   'NONE',
 `uniqueid` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `agent_only` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
 `queue_position` smallint(4) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
 `called_count` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
 `nopaperform` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
 `park_sec` int(3) DEFAULT 0,
 `dispo_sec` int(3) DEFAULT 0,
 `record_file` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`closecallid`),
 KEY `lead_id` (`lead_id`),
 KEY `call_date` (`call_date`),
 KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
 KEY `uniqueid` (`uniqueid`),
 KEY `phone_number` (`phone_number`),
 KEY `date_user` (`call_date`,`user`),
 KEY `closecallid` (`closecallid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1850672 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

EXPLAIN QUERY(On third query only):

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    664640  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  c   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    662480  Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
```

UPDATE(Updated Query):

```
SELECT a.call_date,
       a.lead_id,
       a.phone_number
       AS customer_number,
       IF(a.status != 'DROP', 'ANSWERED', 'UNANSWERED')
       AS status,
       IF(a.lead_id IS NOT NULL, 'inbound', 'outbound')
       AS call_type,
       a.user
       AS agent,
       a.campaign_id
       AS skill,
       NULL
       AS campaign,
       a.status
       AS disposition,
       a.term_reason
       AS Hangup,
       a.uniqueid,
       Sec_to_time(a.queue_seconds)
       AS time_to_answer,
       Sec_to_time(a.length_in_sec - a.queue_seconds)
       AS talk_time,
       Sec_to_time(a.park_sec)
       AS hold_sec,
       Sec_to_time(a.dispo_sec)
       AS wrapup_sec,
       From_unixtime(a.start_epoch)
       AS start_time,
       From_unixtime(a.end_epoch)
       AS end_time,
       c.user
       AS
transfered,
a.comments,
IF(a.length_in_sec IS NULL, Sec_to_time(a.queue_seconds),
Sec_to_time(a.length_in_sec + a.dispo_sec))
       AS duration,
Sec_to_time(a.length_in_sec - a.queue_seconds + a.dispo_sec)
       AS handling_time
FROM   vicidial_closer_log a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN vicidial_closer_log c
                    ON a.closecallid <> c.closecallid
                       AND a.uniqueid = c.uniqueid
                       AND a.closecallid < c.closecallid
WHERE a.call_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-13 23:59:59'
```

EXPLAIN on updated query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL     call_date,date_user     NULL    NULL    NULL    662829  Using where
1   SIMPLE  c   ref     PRIMARY,uniqueid,closecallid    uniqueid    62  aastell_bliss.a.uniqueid    1   Using where
```

Updated Query Execution Result:

```
Number of rows present between given time range: 155016 rows
Time taken: 0.0149 secs
```

It works!

Comment: Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE vicidial_closer_log` as text and put this into the question formatted with `{}`. There's no need to create two temporary tables of vicidial_closer_log. Include `EXPLAIN {query}` also as text.

Comment: @danblack I've updated my question. Can you elaborate on how to remove the use of temporary tables in this query? Thanks

Comment: Your temporary tables don't have indexes. Avoid them anyway by replacing `temp1` and `temp2` in your query with `vicidial_closer_log`. The `a` and `c` aliases means they aren't conflicting. Then show the `EXPLAIN {query}` for that query. `Group by a.closecallid` is odd because its a unique primary key.  Is the `call_date` range of the query important? Are you planning to make it smaller later? Leave it omitted for now.

Comment: if uniqueid is a unique key, it should be defined as such.

Comment: Okay, taking your advice, I've set uniqueid as unique key and removed the temporary tables and it has improved a lot but the date range is critical to the operation and yes i'm planning to make it smaller.

Comment: Thanks @danblack, the performance has improved drastically and i've just used BETWEEN to get the date but its working great. Thank you

Comment: Changing the `call_date` index to `(call_date,uniqueid)` will help with a narrower search range. Can you show the final `EXPLAIN` after these changes?

Comment: Please check the question update. Thanks

Comment: ok. looks good - final tip, as closecallid is the primary key, it doesn't need to be a secondary key as well.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. You helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of comments that lead to an answer:

- `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... SELECT` doesn't create indexes on the temporary table
- Explicit use of a temporary table, particularly of a large size, will rarely give a performance gain.
- Using table aliases in a join allows for a self join
- Group by Primary Key on the left side of a join doesn't add much as its already unique and the `JOIN` had no aggregate expressions. `GROUP BY` adds an implicit `ORDER BY` so you expression could end up slower if a secondary index was used to join the table.
- While the date range of the query was large, preparing for it to be a significant filter when small would make the `call_date` more favourable as an index. To make this more favorable, the join key is added to the end of the index so most of the work of the join can happen by just looking at the index.
- When PK is on a column, a secondary index on the same column isn't needed.